# Why isn't user_data sent to my Google Ads Conversion when I have enabled it in my Google Tag (GTM)

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

In my Google Tag configuration within Google Tag Manager, I have set the `user_data` parameter to a User-Provided Data variable in Shared event settings. My understanding of this is that it will apply to all events managed by my Google tag.

When I add a Google Ads Conversion tag in GTM, I am again given the option to send `user_data` and select this parameter, but this should not be necessary, since I have already set it at the Google Tag configuration level. However, in my testing, the data is not sent in the conversion (the em field is missing from the payload).

Why isn't `user_data` sent to my Google Ads Conversion when I have enabled it in my Google Tag?

Clearly I'm misunderstanding the association between the Google Tag and other Google tags added via GTM and the recent changes in GTM relating to the Google Tag and GA4/Google Ads have completely confused me.